# Start service (By class) returns null in my case

Tags: java, android, reflection

I use [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) to dynamically load an Android `Service` class from a external **dex** file in `onCreate()` callback of `MyActivity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private Class<Object> myServiceClass;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   String dexFile = "path/to/dexFile.dex";
   DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexFile, getDir("tmp", 0).getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

   myServiceClass = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.test.MyService");
   //Here, I am able to use java relfection to successfully get those methods in myServiceClass.
  //so, no problem here!
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
  //PROBLEM HERE: I get null, failed to start service, why?     
  ComponentName name = startService(new Intent(this, myServiceClass.getClass()));
}
```

I have also declared MyService in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```
<service
      android:name="com.test.MyService"
 />
```

Why I get null when **start my service** in `onStart()` callback of `MyActivity` ?

**================ Update (startService() returns the component name now)==========**

After I changed to use `ComponentName name = startService(new Intent(this, myServiceClass));`

The above `startService(...)` returns me the following component name:

```
ComponentInfo{com.project.myapp/com.test.MyService}
```

But my **logcat** also show me the **error**:

```
No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
...
Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.project.myapp/java.lang.Class }: not found
...
...

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.test.MyService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.MyService
12-23 13:50:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2380)
12-23 13:50:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:138)
12-23 13:50:44.040: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
```

Comment: "This class loader requires an application-private, writable directory ...", what is "path/to/dexFile.dex"? Also any specific errors or traces? Can you add Log calls to the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) methods to see which one of them are called? Include one in the constructor as well, see how far it loads up and where it stops.

Comment: Hi, "path/to/dexFile.dex" is in my sdcard directory. I got also the error "Not granting permission android.permission.READ_LOGS"

Comment: sdcard is not application-private. Try to getDir a private directory for it, similar to how you the `tmp` directory for it.

Comment: @soulseekah, I tried to 1st put my dex file in project's assert/ then programmtically copy it to internal storage, after which use the dexClassLoader. It gives me the same result. I am not able to start service still.

Comment: The 1st error message I got is "No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/myapp.apk", please check my update in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you successfully loaded the `Service` class through a custom `ClassLoader`, the Android API calls forget about the actual `Class` instance soon: The `Intent` just drops the `Class` and keeps its name:

From `android.content.Intent` (API 18):

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

From `android.content.ComponentName`:

```
public ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls) {
    mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();
    mClass = cls.getName();
}
```

The `android.app.ActivityThread` then creates the `Service` instance like this:

```
LoadedApk packageInfo = getPackageInfoNoCheck(
        data.info.applicationInfo, data.compatInfo);
Service service = null;
try {
    java.lang.ClassLoader cl = packageInfo.getClassLoader();
    service = (Service) cl.loadClass(data.info.name).newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (!mInstrumentation.onException(service, e)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Unable to instantiate service " + data.info.name
            + ": " + e.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

The package class loader won't be able to load a class that was loaded by a custom [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).  The problem is that caching is - if I remember it correctly, has been some time since I had to implement my own `ClassLoader` - performed by every single `ClassLoader`, e.g. the child `ClassLoader` caches the `Class`es it loaded and the parent does not have access to it.

**Update:**

A workaround is a *wrapper service* which delegates all invocations to a (`Service`) instance that can be loaded using any `ClassLoader`. This can become quite messy, but it might as well solve the problem entirely.

Assuming you have the *wrapper service* `class WrapperService extends Service`, an `interface ExtService` and a `class MyServiceClass implements ExtService` (where `MyServiceClass` can be loaded from your dex file):

- The constructor `public WrapperService()` instantiates the `DexClassLoader`, loads `MyServiceClass` and casts an instance to an `ExtService` which it stores in an instance field.
- `MyServiceClass` gets a reference to the `WrapperService`, either as a constructor parameter or through a method defined in `ExtService`.
- `ExtService` declares all methods which must be invoked by `WrapperService`.
- Instances of `WrapperService` delegate necessary method calls to methods of the `ExtService`.

**Update 2:**

I just read some parts of the Android application ClassLoader (`PathClassLoader` extends `BaseDexClassLoader`) which uses a `final DexPathList` that itself contains a `final` array of a fixed size. This makes common JAVA tricks (such as adding URLs to `URLClassLoader`s) impossible, even if the `SecurityManager` would allow that.

Comment: Hi, seems you haven't checked my updates in my post, I noticed the mistake you mentioned already & corrected it & successfully loaded the service class, the problem now is that I am not able to start the service. I got "Unable to instantiate service". Please check my updateds in my post. thanks.

Comment: your prediction is correct. I got the "Unable to instantiate service" runtime exception even though I have successfully loaded the service class. Do you have any idea how to get rid of this problem ?

Comment: @Mellon I am really sorry, I accidentally skipped your updates. I updated my answer and suggested a workaround although I am currently working on a "real" solution.

Comment: @ still_learning, thanks for your suggestion, I will have a try on it. I am also looking forward to your "real" solution if that is different than your suggestion.

Comment: @Mellon Security on Android systems is quite strong, my initial hope to find a straight solution just went away. See *Update 2*.